# console app question

Tags: c#, console-application, instantiation

> Updated for clarity, hopefully...
>   Yes, I was wondering if there are any use cases to say

```
Program p = new Program();
```

Yes I am referring to the Program class that comes with a new Console App template.

What are some use cases where you would want to instantiate the Program class in a c# console app?

Comment: This is a very general question. You would instantiate it if you have a reason to? I guess? Is there a specific thing you have a problem with?

Comment: could you post some sample code to clarify what you are looking for? When you say "Program class" -- do you mean the `class Program` that shows from the default console template? And why "console app" -- since `class Program` also appears in the WinForms template (okay, it shows up as `static class Program` but you can delete `static` and instantiate it if you want).

Comment: Since the Program class also shows up by default in the WinForms App template, the references to "Console App" are confusing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you, say, want to run multiple threads (as in a service app), each with their own copy of `Program`, it's useful to be able to:

```
Program p = new Program();
```

`Main()` won't automatically be called in these instances. This lets you, say, create service threads if the app is running as a service, or run some interactive console code within `main()`, depending on how the app was started. This is very handy when debugging services.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't need a GUI -- when you don't need user input. Or you only need very simple user input (say..... in test code).

If your app will be running unattended on a server -- why have the overhead of an un-viewed form?

Comment: You need to read his question closer. He's asking why you would want to do `Program p = new Program()`

Comment: well, he didn't _say_ that; when you run a console app, you _are_ instantiating a program class -- otherwise nothing would happen. If you are correct, he should have said something along the lines of "instantiate additional Program classes".

Comment: @Michael: Actually, you don't instantiate any class by default. The runtime calls the `static void Main(string[])` method on the `Program` class. And, this applies to both console and windowed applications.

Comment: @Mike Caron: A static class is still constructed, so it is still instantiated.

Comment: @Matt Ellen: A class has its static members initialized, but it's not constructed (i.e. instantiated) in any way unless you call `new`.

Comment: @Mike Caron -- I was wrong wrong wrong. The static Main method is called without any instantion of the default Program class. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685692/c-console-application-static-methods/1685704#1685704 Gotcha. BUT, I'm not getting that out of the original question. Reading the question closely, there are multiple interpretations. Why is "console app" specified, f'r instance, when the same behavior exists for WinForm apps? I think that's what everybody focuses on, in the lack of clarity. You assume the OP means `Program p - new Program();`, just as we assume otherwise

Comment: @Michael: True. The only way know for sure would be for the **OP to clarify his question** ;)

Answer (score 0):

If good UI was not something you needed, but you do still need to display something.

I have written Win forms apps that could be executed silently... that is without showing the form, executing, then ending.

One very good reason might be to make sure an app can run when no GUI can be.  On many linux servers and Windows Core installs GUI apps are not an option.

Comment: You need to read his question closer. He's asking why you would want to do `Program p = new Program()`