# Calling Methods from the Main to return values C#

Tags: c#, methods

I am trying to get values to show up on the command line for the DisplayResults, GetLength, DeterminePrice, and DetermineSale

I am getting errors on what I have on my Main () file.

First File:

```
//Alma Villasenor

using System;

namespace Assingment3
{
    class Info
    {

        public void DisplayInfo()
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Alma Villasenor");
            System.Console.WriteLine("C#");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Judith L");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Assignment3A");
            System.Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }
}
```

Second File

```
//Alma Villasenor
using System;

namespace Assignment3
{
    class MathOperations
    {
        public double DisplayResults(int avalue, int bvalue)
        {

            avalue = 50;

            bvalue = 51;

            double Results = (avalue + bvalue);

            return Results;

        }

        public double GetLength(int cvalue, int dvalue)
        {

            cvalue = 25;

            dvalue = 12;

            double Length = (cvalue / dvalue);

            return Length;

        }

        public double GetPrice(int evalue, int fvalue)
        {

            evalue = 100;

            fvalue = 25;

            double Price = (evalue * fvalue);

            return Price;

        }

        public double DetermineSale(int gvalue, int hvalue)
        {

            gvalue = 30;

            hvalue = 4;

            double Sale = (gvalue - hvalue);

            return Sale;



        }



    }
}
```

Third file (where I need to call my Methods/Class to display the results:

```
//Alma Villasenor
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Assingment3
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Info myinfo = new Info();
            myinfo.DisplayInfo();


            Assignment3.MathOperations.DisplayResults();


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

any help?

Comment: Plz thell us what errors you get.

Comment: When you get an error during compilation it is a good idea to describe it here alongside the line that causes it - see [How to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). About the problem: `Assignment3.MathOperations.DisplayResults` is not a static method, so you can't call it using class name. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685692/c-sharp-console-application-static-methods may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2):

First if you are not declaring the class MathOperations, you need to have the methods much as DisplayResults as **static**, and also since DisplayResults returns a boolean value, assign it to a variable or display it as System.Console.WriteLine(MathOperations.DisplayResults());

Answer (score 0):

Within your `Main` method you need to create an instance of the `MathOperations` class. Then, you need to write to the `Console` the result of the method calls.

```
// Inside Main()
var math = new MathOperations();
Console.WriteLine(math.DisplayResults(a, b));
```

Or, make methods in the `MathOperations` class static.

```
public static double DisplayResults(int avalue, int bvalue)
{
    avalue = 50;
    bvalue = 51;
    double Results = (avalue + bvalue);
    return Results;
}
```

This will allow you to call this method without creating an instance of the `MathOperations` class.

```
// Inside Main()
Console.WriteLine(MathOperations.DisplayResults(a, b));
```

Comment: It doesn't need to be public, when you don't specify it implicitly is internal

Comment: Yes, true. Removed from the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

First, the call `Assignment3.MathOperations.DisplayResults();` is not allowed as you're accessing it from the Main-method, which is static. The method DisplayResults() in the class MathOperations is not. Either make the method static, or make an instance and call the method on that instance.

Second, you specify that the method should have the signature: `DisplayResults(int avalue, int bvalue)`. This means that it is expected that you invoke it with two arguments (`avalue` and `bvalue`), while you invoke it with none.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void Main()
{
    Info myinfo = new Info();
    myinfo.DisplayInfo();


    //Assignment3.MathOperations.DisplayResults();
    //you need to create an instance of MathOperations before you can call the
    //non-static DisplayResults() method.
      MathOperations operation = new MathOperations();
    //capture your return value
      double result = operation.DisplayResults(someValue, someOtherValue);
      Console.WriteLine(result);


      Console.ReadLine();
}
```

If you really want to call the DisplayResults() using the class name, you better declare the method as static:

```
public static double DisplayResults(int avalue, int bvalue)
```

But remember to capture your return value if you want to do something with it.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you are trying to use the `DisplayResults` as a static method.
Unless you declare it static in your second file, you need to create an instance of the class `MathOperations`.
In this case you just need to use:

```
MathOperations ops = new MathOperations();
Console.WriteLine(ops.DisplayResults());
```

Also, for the first file, if you import the namespace System (using System statement) you don't need to specify it when calling the Console.WriteLine method:

```
using System;

namespace Assingment3
{
    class Info
    {

        public void DisplayInfo()
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Alma Villasenor");
           Console.WriteLine("C#");
           Console.WriteLine("Judith L");
           Console.WriteLine("Assignment3A");
           Console.WriteLine(System.DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        }
    }
}
```